# Fatal Exception in my android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, exception

I'm getting a fatal exception that seems to be caused by a nullpointer exception. The Logcat is pointing me to java line 39 which is in  my onCreate method. Here's my onCreate and my Global variables.

```
GestureLibrary mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
    Resources res;
    String [] letters;
    int i = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (!mLibrary.load())
        {
           finish();
        }


        res = getResources();
        letters = res.getStringArray(R.array.LetterToBeDrawn);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv.setText("Draw the letter: "+letters[i]);

        GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView)findViewById(R.id.gestures);
        gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
    }
```

This all seems fine to me so I have no idea why it would be giving a nullpointer exception. My xml file looks fine to me as well:

```
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/gestures"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:fadeOffset="1000"
    android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />

</android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
```

Logcat:

```
04-30 10:48:48.418: D/dalvikvm(1465): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 248K, 10% free 3137K/3452K, paused 86ms, total 96ms
04-30 10:48:48.418: D/AndroidRuntime(1465): Shutting down VM
04-30 10:48:48.428: W/dalvikvm(1465): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a84ba8)
04-30 10:48:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1465): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 10:48:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1465): Process: com.gmail.Sheridjohn.letterchecker, PID: 1465
04-30 10:48:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1465): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gmail.Sheridjohn.letterchecker/com.gmail.Sheridjohn.letterchecker.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-30 10:48:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1465):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-30 10:48:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1465):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-30 10:48:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1465):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-30 10:48:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1465):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-30 10:48:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1465):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-30 10:48:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1465):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-30 10:48:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1465):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-30 10:48:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1465):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 10:48:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1465):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-30 10:48:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1465):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-30 10:48:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1465):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-30 10:48:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1465):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-30 10:48:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1465): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-30 10:48:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1465):     at com.gmail.Sheridjohn.letterchecker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
04-30 10:48:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1465):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-30 10:48:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1465):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-30 10:48:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1465):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-30 10:48:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1465):     ... 11 more
04-30 10:48:54.378: I/Process(1465): Sending signal. PID: 1465 SIG: 9
```

EDIT: I've changed mLibrary to null then initialise it in my OnCreate but it's still breaking on line 39 which is:

```
tv.setText("Draw the letter: "+letters[i]);
```

Comment: can you please format the stack trace correctly? Thanks

Comment: Please show me line 39.

Comment: What are your "global variables"?

Comment: what's at the `MainActivity.java:39`?

Comment: Someone may correct me here, but, why are you running finish(); right in the middle of the onCreate?  I'm pretty sure that will kill the activity.

Comment: @durbnpoisn - I don't think it's actually getting that far, but yes that looks a bit strange. I think mLibrary is null, at a guess.

Comment: Which one is line 39?

Comment: We don't know. Amazing how often you see questions like this isn't it?

Comment: Line 39 is:
tv.setText("Draw the letter: "+letters[i]);

Comment: @Andrew...  I think the reason for that is that as nice is LogCat is, it doesn't tell the whole story.

Answer (score 3):

first problem is here:

```
GestureLibrary mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
```

Correct way is:

```
GestureLibrary mLibrary = null;
Resources res;
String [] letters;
int i = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);

    if (!mLibrary.load())
    {
       finish();
    }


    res = getResources();
    letters = res.getStringArray(R.array.LetterToBeDrawn);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    tv.setText("Draw the letter: "+letters[i]);

    GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView)findViewById(R.id.gestures);
    gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
}
```